# How to accredit my Ph.D. in USA

Tags: phd, thesis, united-states, accreditation

I got my Ph.D. from the Faculty of Computers and Information Technology, Cairo University in 2007. I want to know if it is possible to compensate or to accredit my Ph.D. from USA. If it is possible, I want to know the steps for that. Advise and tell me if there is any program in USA for a Ph.D. holder to improve and add on to his career.

Comment: I have made some edits. Please see if they are what you wanted to ask. 'compensate' has a monetary tone to it and I am not very sure why someone should accredit a PhD degree.

Comment: Despite Bravo's edits, I don't understand the question.  Do you want to convince someone (who?) that you really have a PhD from Cairo?  Do you want to convince someone (who?) that the FCI PhD program at Cairo is legitimate?  Or do you want to leverage your existing PhD to obtain another degree in the US?

Answer (score 14):

In the U.S., most academic fields are not like medicine: there is no licensing and for most purposes there are not strict legal requirements for what constitutes a degree.  In particular, there is nothing that needs to or can be done to accredit a foreign Ph.D.  (Other countries may differ.  For example, Germany used to treat non-EU Ph.D.'s differently; see http://www.zeit.de/2008/12/C-Seitenhieb-12.)

Regarding more specific issues:

Employers sometimes verify CVs, but that is not your responsibility.  If they need to check that you have a legitimate Ph.D. from Cairo University, then they will get in touch with the university directly to verify this.  You do not need to help (and in fact they won't allow you to help, to make sure the verification is unbiased), so all you need to do is to make sure everything on your CV is true.

You may run into people who acknowledge that you have a legitimate Ph.D. but have no idea what the standards of Cairo University are.  That will give you a modest disadvantage compared with students from, say, Stanford, but there's nothing you can do about it.  Ultimately, if you publish strong papers in prestigious venues, then that will matter much more than where your Ph.D. is from.  If you don't, then you will not get a research job anyway, wherever you studied.

If you are talking about upgrading the degree somehow - perhaps getting additional certification or even another degree from a particularly prestigious school - then it basically can't be done.  It's not truly impossible, and I know of a couple of cases in which people with Ph.D.s from other countries enrolled as students in the U.S. in order to improve their job chances.  However, most U.S. universities strongly discourage this, on the grounds that it's a waste of time and resources to devote a space in a graduate program to someone who already has a Ph.D. in the same field (or a closely related one).

Comment: "Employers sometimes verify CVs, but that is not your responsibility." There is one part of that which *may* end up being your responsibility. Employers sometimes ask for _certified_ "local language" translations of diploma. That is often provided by most professional translation services.

Comment: *"there are no legal requirements for what constitutes a degree."* Is correct as far as it goes, but perhaps too encouraging. Most organizations (including various branches of the government) have a policy of expecting degrees to come from accredited institutions, and people have gotten dismissed for representing non-accredited degrees as equivalent to accredited ones. They will probably have to deal with foreign diplomas on a per case basis, but they are still looking for an assurance of that the degree means something similar to the accredited degrees they are used to.

Comment: @dmckee: Good point.  I'll edit to weaken it a little.

Answer (score 8):

Although it is not possible to "accredit" a foreign degree, there are services out there that will determine if your foreign degree is equivalent to a degree issued by an accredited university in the United States. This type of service might be useful for immigration purposes and it might be necessary to apply for certain jobs in the United States, especially in the public sector. [There are lists of  foreign degree equivalency service providers available.](http://www.osp.state.nc.us/ExternalHome/Group5/LocalGovmt/ForeignDegreeEquiv.pdf)

If you look at the services offered by Educational Credential Evaluators, the reports [that can be purchased](https://www.ece.org/main/content=EvaluationServices&SubSite=1&LeftNav=2) vary in detail (and, of course, cost).  These reports are not cheap and, in most instances, probably unnecessary, so I would hold off on getting one done until I'm positive I'll need one.